# Handle big x values in endless runner game

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm about to start my second endless runner game in box2d and I like to avoid a problem with very high x values I had with the first.

As game is endless and the player is always going right (with a camera following him) I'm experiencing float precision problems.
Not only for object positioning, but for drawing as well.

How could I move all the world content to the left to avoid such high values without seeing any major glitches when I move everything?

I guess not, but, can I avoid iterating over all the bodies?

Answer (score 2):

> Why take Mohammad to the Mountain when you can bring the mountain to Mohammad?

You only have to create the *illusion* of endlessness, and don't have to worry about high `x` values at all.  Let's assume your character is in the middle of the screen and running right.  Well, he never moves, does he?  You just move the immediate world past him.  Assuming that you're generating the world on the fly (a good presumption as this is an endless running game), you generate it and move it past the player creating the illusion that the world is endless.

But the player never moves!

Comment: Don't know how is this going to work with box2d... Have you ever tried it? I suppose I could try to use kinematic bodies instead of static ones, but how about other objects? Should I apply movement to all of them manually?